# To find the doubling map of the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+1$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I want to verify that the doubling map of the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+1$ is given by
\begin{align}
 P=(x,y) &\to 2P \\
 (x,y) &\mapsto \left(\frac{x^4-8x}{4x^3+4}, \frac{2x^6+40x^3}{8y^3} \right)
\end{align}

---

For calculation flexibility we denote $P=(x',y')$. We will find the tangent line at $P$ and make intersect with the curve to find $2P$.

Differentiating the curve with respect to $x$, we get $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{3x^2}{2y}.$$
So the tangent line at $P$ is given by $$y-y'=\frac{3x'^2}{2y'}(x-x') \Rightarrow y=\frac{3x'^2x-3x'^3+2y'^2}{2y'}.$$
Substituting $y$ in the curve, we get
\begin{align}
&\left(\frac{3x'^2x-3x'^3+2y'^2}{2y'} \right)^2=x^3+1 \\
&\Rightarrow (3x'^2x-3x'^3+2y'^2)^2=4y'^2x^3+4y'^2 \\
&\Rightarrow 9x'^4x^2+9x'^6+4y'^4+18x'^5x+12x'^3y'^2-12x'^2y'^2x=4y'^2x^3+4y'^2 \\
& \Rightarrow 4y'^2x^3-9x'^4x^2+(12x'^2y'^2-18x'^5)x+(4y'^2-9x'^6-4y'^4-12x'^3y'^2)=0, \cdots (1)
\end{align}
The elliptic passes through $(0,1)$, and hence plugging it in $(1)$, we get
$$4y'^2-9x'^6-4y'^4-12x'^3y'^2=0, \cdots (2)$$
But now I am out of way, how to solve for $x', y'$ ?

> what is the apropriate way to solve my question ?

Comment: You have a linear equation relating $x$ and $y$ since the third intersection point must be on the tangent line. Then, since the third intersection point is also on the curve, you can substitute the linear equation into the equation for the curve to get a cubic equation. The cubic has a double root at $x = x'$ so use polynomial long division to divide it by $(x - x')^2$. Then, the result should be a linear equation whose solution is the third intersection point.

Comment: @DavidLui, You mean to divide cubic equation $(1)$ by the factor $(x-x')^2$. But  $y'$ is also involved in $(1)$.

Comment: You should treat $x'$ and $y'$ as numbers, not variables. Moreover, you may consider the equality $(x-b)(x-x'^2) = $ and use the sum and addition of roots rules to derive faster.

Comment: @kelalaka, yes  I treating them as numbers or constants but the divison is not easy. Anyway, I hope your next trick will help

Comment: It must be $(x-b)(x-x')^2 = \cdotd$, soorry.

Comment: You can post your answer, at least I'll post. These steps are usually not written in books...

Comment: @kelalaka, I answered my own question. Thanks to you and David Lui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to check optically the claimed formula on an obvious example of choice, taking $Q=(0,1)$, since the two denominators are divisible by $x$, thus getting $2Q\overset?=(0,0)$. Not a point on the curve. What happens here?

---

My way of computing is as follows. Consider the point $P=(u,v)$ on the elliptic curve with affine equation $Y^2 =X^3 +1$. Then the tangent line to the given curve in $(u,v)$ is $2Y\; dY=3X^2\; dX$, which taken in $(u,v)$ is $2v(Y-v) = 3u^2(X-u)$. We isolate and replace $Y$ from this equation, it is $Y=mx+n$ with $$m=\frac{3u^2}{2v}\ ,$$
into $-Y^2 + X^3 +\dots$ to get $0 = X^3 -m^2X^2+\dots$, and we already know two roots (with multiplicity counted), which are $u,u$, so the third root, $x$, is given by (Vieta) $u+u+x=m^2$. So
$$
x = -2u+m^2 
= -2u + \frac {9u^4}{4v^2}
=  \frac {-8uv^2 + 9u^4}{4v^2}
=   \frac {-8u(u^3+1) + 9u^4}{4v^2}
=   \frac {u^4-8u}{4(u^3+1)}
\ .
$$
To get the $Y$-component $y'$ of $-2P=(x,y')$, we use
$$
\begin{aligned}
y'&=mx+n=m(-2u+m^2)+n=-2mu+m^3+(v-mu)
=v-3mu+m^3
\\
&=\frac 1{8v^3}(8v^4-36u^3v^2+27u^6)\text{ which is either}
\\
&=\frac1{8v^3}(8v^4-36(v^2-1)v^2+27(v^2-1)^2)
=\frac1{8v^3}(-v^4-18v^2+27)\text{ or}
\\
&=\frac1{8v^3}(8(u^3+1)^2-36u^3(u^3+1)+27u^6)
=\frac1{8v^3}(-u^6-20u^3\color{red}{+8})\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
This gives for $(x,y)=2P=-(x,y')=(x,y)$ the formula:
$$
2P=(x,y)=
\left(\ 
\frac {u^4-8u}{4(u^3+1)}\ ,\ 
\frac{u^6+20u^3\color{red}{-8}}{8v^3}\ \right)\ .
$$

---

Chech using the point $Q=(0,1)$: Applying the above formula we get $2Q=(0,-1)$, which is a point on the curve.

---

Sage check (using the implemented sage formula for the field $K$, which is the fraction field of the ring $R=\Bbb Q[U,V]/(V^2 -(U^3+1))$):

```
F.<U,V> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
R.<u,v> = F.quotient(V^2 - U^3 - 1)
K = FractionField(R)

E = EllipticCurve(K, [0, 1])
P = E.point([u, v])
print(f'P = {P.xy()}')
print(f'2P = {(2*P).xy()}')
```

This gives:

```
P = (u, v)
2P = ((u*v^2 - 9*u)/(4*v^2), (v^4 + 18*v^2 - 27)/(8*v^3))
```

Comment: Thank you. The 2nd last line missing `)`

Comment: Yes, thanks for the hint, i was editing elsewhere the few lines en bloc, then copy+pasted it... Often when the sage interpreter makes problem there is so simple to correct the white noise error in place, see that it works. Then it works, so i also almost always forget to correct also in the editor (emacs in my case)... OK, now it should be fine!

Answer (score 1):

As hinted by @David Lui and @kelalaka, I would like to answer partially.

The elliptic curve is $y^2=x^3+1$. The tangent line at $P=(x',y')$ is $$L: y=\frac{3x'^2x-3x'^3+2y'^2}{2y'}.$$
Substituting $L$ in the elleiptic curve, we get
$$4y'^2x^3-9x'^4x^2+(12x'^2y'^2-18x'^5)x+(4y'^2-9x'^6-4y'^4-12x'^3y'^2)=0,$$
which is a cubic equation with doubale zero $x'$. If $b$ be another zero of this cubic equation, then by theory of equations we have the folowing relation:
\begin{align} &2x'+b=x'+x'+b=\frac{9x'^4}{4y'^2} \\ \Rightarrow &b=\frac{9x'^4}{4y'^2}-2x' \\ \Rightarrow &b=\frac{9x'^4}{4(x'^3+1)}-2x', ~~(\because y'^2=x'^3+1) \\
\Rightarrow &b=\frac{x'^4-8x'}{4x'^3+4}:=x   \end{align}
Now substituting $\frac{x'^4-8x'}{4x'^3+4}:=x $ in the tangent line and using $y'^2=x'^3+1$, we get
\begin{align}y=\frac{2x'^6+40x'^3}{8y'^3}.   \end{align}
Therefore $2P=\left(\frac{x^4-8x}{4x^3+4}, \frac{2x^6+40x^3}{8y^3} \right)$. This concludes the doubling map.

Comment: You see, this is shorter. Did you check the result with SageMath?

Comment: @kelalaka, i never used sageMath. But I would to check. Can you help me with sageMath ?

Comment: [Here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyFjsFqwzAQRO-B_MPii2VXdop8C-RLSgyqIhkfahlJDnJK_72zDsS99SDY3Zl5o7sOosylLFe8hPcoq-NhoAvlvqM3Rc3aq-NhDuOURMH3Qg5wJD0lLKKrU6_qTA3xhASp-tErqk5C1al6JeEfLEcKyVEIDvGhjctnFN_r-T_Qz44yS7hb0tONGAqgY5rN4LnW5hmK2N2Onid7427YIBlvHddja7d5NCM-F0WWFGcdor28_-nbHaSN8bii2lNm4CbCG5evCGKz7R_qenoO3fWF2RzeUfA-xULyWv0C2TRwvA==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==), until some of the roots, You may have some error or me ( note $t =x'$ and $z=y'$)

Comment: @kelalaka, thank you very much. I see you calculated the sum of the roots of cubic equation $(1)$.  Thats what you meant in 1st comment "to check the my answer with sageMath" ?

Comment: Yes, there are two ways, one is finding a point and comparing the doubling results for random points, or calculating the equations programmatically. I go to the second one.

Comment: @kelalaka, ok thanks. Can you tell me what is the function `sparse=0` in your source code ? What does it do ?

Comment: The difference is here; seach for coefficients, https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/calculus/sage/symbolic/expression.html